# What form do I declare RSU payouts on for my taxes?

Tags: united-states, rsu, tax-forms

My company sold and I had RSU's.  They gave me a K-1 form but it doesn't show what I was paid, only what was paid in on my behalf.

I have not received a w-2 for the payout.  Is there a specific form I need to fill out to pay the taxes on this income? (no taxes were withheld).

HELP!!!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you received cash, not shares? Did you work for this company in the year the RSUs vested? Did you receive a W-2 for your wages? If so, are you sure it doesn’t include the income from the RSUs?

Comment: Sounds like you need a professional to sort through this with you. The form that you receive that shows a payout will dictate how you report the income. If it doesn't show up on the K-1 (you were a partner in the company?) then perhaps there's still a 1099 to come.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities in your case. You would need to identify and sort out with the relevant contacts i.e., employer or the plan administrator appointed by the employer.

1st scenario : your company decided to payout all RSUs with a fixed value. This value will be the offer price stated by the takeover company. In this case your employer has to issue a W2 as the settlement was completed in form of CASH. The cash inflow can be from your current employer or the overtaking company (should not matter).

2nd scenario:  employer decided to pay you by selling all your shares in market and send cash proceeds to you. These shares can be funded by overtaking company in some cases. In this case, the broker ( may be custodian appointed by the employer ) should issue you 1099-B statement as underlying market transaction was taken place. The broker can be the plan administrator as well.